# Need Clarification on Uipath Licensing

Tags: automation, licensing, rpa, uipath

I need information on UiPath licensing.

Let’s say I’ve 2 bots and I want to run these 2 bots in **parallel** in 20 different VMs.  So, in these cases do I need to have 2 bot licenses or 20 bot licenses?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about software licensing are [off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/6471538).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964) You may be able to get help on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com), but [**read their faq carefully** before proceeding](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7265). Legal questions may be asked on [Law.SE](//law.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 5):

In general, a bot is regarded as the entity that executes the process/sequence. So, in your case, you would need two concurrent licenses to run the bots in parallel on 20 different VMs provided that the processes are executed and completed sequentially. You could even use a single license for this. If you need all processes to run simultaneously then you would require 20 bots each with its own license.

However, UiPath offer many different licenses for studio, orchestrator, and robots that I’ll detail below and it may be that there are other license types that better support simultaneous executions.

**UiPath - Attended Robot - Concurrent User**
Concurrent licenses are available ONLY in the case of Orchestrator scenario. 1 connected user, unlimited users and workstations defined. Attended Concurrent User License - the No. of Attended Concurrent user licenses purchased equals the maximum number of users who are allowed to simultaneously connect their attended robot to Orchestrator, regardless of the number of user and machines defined in Orchestrator.

**UiPath - Unattended Robot - Concurrent Runtime**
Concurrent licenses are available ONLY in the case of Orchestrator scenario. 1 active runtime, unlimited users and workstations defined. Unattended Concurrent Runtime License - the No. of Unattended Concurrent Runtime licenses purchased equals the maximum number of unattended robots that are able to execute back office processes simultaneously, regardless of the number of users and machines defined in Orchestrator.

**UiPath - Orchestrator**
Robot Management and Control System supporting: release management, centralized logging,
reporting, auditing and monitoring tools, remote control, centralized scheduling, queue / robot workload management, assets management. It provides a limited amount of tenants (e.g. separate logical environments of robots, processes, users and systems and data).

**UiPath - Studio - Named User**
One named user can access the Studio.  UiPath Studio is the Process & Workflow Designer tool.  It runs only on Windows like the robot which mimicks the user keystrokes of the target Desktop environment.  It enables users to automate with highly intuitive tools (not code):  process recorders, drag & drop widgets, re-use best practices templates or refer to other work libraries.

**UiPath - Studio - Node Locked**
Node locked licensing includes the Studio installation on one machine but multiple users can login in. UiPath Studio is our Process and Workflow Designer tool. It runs only on Windows like the robot which mimicks the user keystrokes of the target Desktop environment. It enables users to automate with highly intuitive tools (not code): process recorders, drag and drop widgets, re-use best practices templates or refer to other workflow libraries.

**UiPath - Unattended Robot - Node Locked** 
Unattended robot runtime executes RPA workflows for back office activities. It is controlled, deployed and managed by our central process automation system - the Orchestrator. It runs on a virtual desktop, in a secure session, end-to-end, without human intervention. It performs the process end to end, 'lights out' - working business transactions with the help of an RPA work queue.

**UiPath - Attended Robot - Named User**
This robot runtime is connected to an authorized licensed user. Attended robot runtime executes RPA workflows, augments human activity, deployed and running on a desktop, triggered based on a human activity, can provide guidance and assistance and is under direct user control.

**UiPath - Attended Robot - Node Locked**
Attended robot runtime executes RPA workflows, augments human activity, deployed and running on a desktop, triggered based on a human activity. It can provide guidance and assistance and is under direct user control. Multiple users can login and run on it at a time, linked to a PC or Virtual Desktop.

Just my two cents though. Hope it helps.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I think you need more clarification around your current set up:

- **Robot (Bot)** - the VM or machine that the automation runs on.
- **Automation** - the process you have automated using UiPath

Assuming that by Bot you mean an automation created in UiPath and you would like to run this on 20 VMs then you would need 20 Licences.

The licences are linked to a Robots not to automations.

Comment: Hi, 

I am interested in bit more explanation on this: "The licences are linked to a Robots not to automations".  If I create a bot to perform say 10 different activities (ex: Get voice input, read email base on that, do OCR on attachment, call an API,  get the respose, open Excel, read content, call another api etc etc. you get what I mean?), do I still need only one attended/unattended bot license?

Comment: In short yes. a single robot could carry out an infinite number of tasks but would only ever need one licence. If you think of your pc, you can browse the internet, play games, word processing, spreadsheets etc etc but you only need on windows licence for windows 7.