# How to find the UiPath Orchestrator license type and information about the limitations of robots running in parallel?

Tags: uipath

I would  like to know how many robots can I run in parallel from my UiPath Orchestrator and where can i find those sort of information?

I came across this [Need Clarification on Uipath Licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295637/need-calcification-on-uipath-licensing?rq=1) where I can see the license types and it's description, however I am not sure how can I check on my Orchestrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Licenses in Orchestrator are assigned on a Tenant level, and one instance of Orchestrator can be used to manage multiple Tenants. If you just want to see how many licenses are assigned, click on the corresponding link:

[image]

You'll be looking for runtimes (either Unattended or NonProduction), and this will tell you how many robots may run in parallel. UiPath offers the following example (copied from [here](https://orchestrator.uipath.com/v2018.2/docs/about-licensing#section-unattended-or-nonproduction)):

> For example, if on a machine with 5 Robots, you assign only 3
>   runtimes, it means only 3 licenses are consumed. If you execute 5 jobs
>   or schedule all the Robots on that machine, the following occurs:
>
> - 3 jobs are executed on the first 3 licensed Robots;
> - the remaining 2 unlicensed Robots are placed in a pending state;
> - the first 3 Robots release their licenses;
> - the remaining 2 Robots are licensed and they execute the assigned jobs.

Some more details about assigning licenses to tenants:

1. The Orchestrator Guide explains the process of [managing licenses](https://orchestrator.uipath.com/docs/managing-your-licenses) and assigning them to Tenants in greater detail.
2. You can also see how many licenses currently are assigned, and modify them from the [Tenants page](https://orchestrator.uipath.com/docs/managing-tenants#section-as-a-host-admin).
3. Different license types are explained in greater detail [here](https://orchestrator.uipath.com/v2018.2/docs/about-licensing#section-licensing-concepts)
4. There's also a training available at their [Academy](https://academy.uipath.com/learn/course/internal/view/elearning/447/UiPathLicensingTraining/enroll) (yet, you will need to be approved based on active licensing).